# Where do I add android:allowAudioPlaybackCapture on the manifest file?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've been reading this guide https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/playback-capture#capture_policy and it says I need to "include android:allowAudioPlaybackCapture="true in the app's manifest.xml file" but how exactly do I accomplish that?
I tried adding the flag on the application header but the compiler just gave me an error.

Edit: Turns out I just needed to set my build tools version >= 28 and my compileSdkVersion to >= 29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to place it in the `<application` tag.

Reference from this article:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/07/capturing-audio-in-android-q.html

I hope it helps!

**Edit:**

If this doesn't work, try the second option referenced in your article https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#setAllowedCapturePolicy(int)

Comment: uhhh the app that im trying to compile is only has compileSdkVersion set to 27 so I don't think that would work, I tried the first solution too but the compiler gave me an error :(

Comment: /root/osu-droid/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/proc
essDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml:24: error: attribute
android:allowAudioPlaybackCapture not found.
  error: failed processing manifest.

Comment: instead of `<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:largeHeap="true" android:isGame="true" android:allowAudioPlaybackCapture="true"` try: `<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:largeHeap="true" android:isGame="true"> android:allowAudioPlaybackCapture="true"/>`

Comment: where `android:allowAudioPlaybackCapture="true"/>` is a new line

Comment: i did just that but it still gave me an error https://i.ibb.co/YW2LB85/IMG-20200629-022633.jpg

Comment: I think you need to make sure you close the tag correctly `/>`

Comment: oh the closing tag is at the very bottom of the manifest

Comment: I see but I believe that you need to close this tag as well some how

Comment: I found the fix for it, it turns out I just needed to update my build tools version to 28 and compile sdk to 29. Sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I just needed to update my buildTools version to 28+ and compileSdk to 29+ on the `build.gradle` file.